# How to select a point from existing points within each grid in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, select

**How to select a point from existing points within each grid cell in QGIS?**

Each grid cell has multiple points and these points have 3 possible values for the "Status" attribute *(Status: A, B or C)*.

[image: point layer's attribute]

Selection condition is:

```
when,
there is no point in a cell, then leave it.
else,
there is only one point, then pick that point.
else,
there are more than one point, then select a point with "Status" = A, if there is no A then select a point with "Status" = B, if there is no A & B then select a point with "Status" = C.
```

(The custom size of the grid is 25-meter x 25 meter.)

Comment: Your title says "randomly select a point", but your selection criteria are not random. Please [edit] your question and clarify what you're actually asking.

Comment: @csk You are right if there is one or not points into the cell grid. However, if exist more than one points you can produce a random number for randomly selecting one of them.

Comment: But this question specifically says to select them according to this rule: "select point A, if there is no A then select point B, if There is no A & B then select point C". That's not random.

Comment: @csk Yes, but it is a confusing wording. For example, If you have three A points you cannot arbitrarily select the first one.  You need to use a statistic basis.

Comment: @xunilk Yes, I see now. The wording confused me: I didn't realize there could be multiple points with the same (A, B or C) value within each cell. I edited the question to hopefully reduce the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

By using PyQGIS is necessary to test the code with appropriate layers. So, I created a 25x25 m grid and a random point layer (100 points) with a field named 'tree_stat' (with randomly values between 'A' and 'C'; as it shows at following image:

[image]

and where it can also be observed cells without any points.

Following code was developed for grouping by grid ids, points ids and, finally, attribute ('tree_stat').

```
from operator import itemgetter
import collections

registry = QgsProject.instance()

points = registry.mapLayersByName('points')
grid = registry.mapLayersByName('grid_25_25')

feats_points = [ feat for feat in points[0].getFeatures() ]
feats_grid = [ feat for feat in grid[0].getFeatures() ]

idxs = [ [i,j] for i,feat_p in enumerate(points[0].getFeatures()) 
               for j,feat_g in enumerate(feats_grid)
               if feat_p.geometry().within(feat_g.geometry()) ]

points_in = [ [] for i in range(len(feats_grid)) ] 

idxs.sort(key = itemgetter(1))

unique = []

for item in idxs:
    if item[1] not in unique:
        unique.append(item[1])

grid_ids =  []
points_ids =  []

for item in idxs:
    grid_ids.append(item[1])
    points_ids.append(item[0])

count = collections.Counter(grid_ids)

#grouping by grid_ids
s = [[k]*v for k, v in collections.Counter(grid_ids).items()]

#grouping by points_ids
h = [ [] for i in range(len(s)) ] 

cont1 = 0
cont2 = 0

for item in s:
    for element in item:
        h[cont1].append(points_ids[cont2])
        cont2 += 1
    cont1 += 1

#grouping by attributes
attr = [ [] for i in range(len(s)) ]

for i, item in enumerate(h):
    for element in item:
        attr[i].append(feats_points[element].attribute('tree_stat'))

#printing results
for i, item in enumerate(h):
    print (unique[i], item)

for i, item in enumerate(attr):
    print(unique[i], item)
```

After running above code, between printed results in Python Console, it was selected cell with id=11; whose 'within' points are into red rectangle of below image. These features were marked in each attributes table and they were adequately selected; as it can be observed at following image. So, code works as expected.

[image]

All grid and points ids values obtained:

```
0 [28]
1 [4, 18, 67, 90]
2 [5, 17]
3 [48, 59, 73]
4 [42]
5 [1]
7 [64]
9 [79, 99]
10 [6, 12, 30]
11 [23, 35, 49, 80, 87, 89, 95]
12 [58, 88]
13 [14, 15, 68]
14 [78]
16 [34, 46]
17 [25, 33, 83, 93]
18 [27, 40, 63, 86]
19 [52, 56, 74, 92]
20 [65]
21 [32, 81]
22 [2, 45, 47]
23 [21, 57]
24 [75, 82, 85]
25 [20]
26 [8, 43, 51, 97]
27 [19, 37, 84]
29 [22, 69]
30 [10]
31 [9, 44, 54]
32 [39, 98]
33 [7, 13, 26, 55]
34 [0]
35 [11, 60, 76, 91]
36 [72]
37 [3, 36, 41]
38 [50, 66]
39 [70, 77]
40 [29]
42 [38, 61]
43 [71]
44 [31, 96]
45 [94]
46 [16, 53]
47 [24, 62]
```

All attribute values obtained:

```
0 ['A']
1 ['A', 'C', 'C', 'A']
2 ['B', 'C']
3 ['A', 'C', 'A']
4 ['C']
5 ['A']
7 ['B']
9 ['C', 'B']
10 ['C', 'B', 'A']
11 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C']
12 ['A', 'B']
13 ['C', 'A', 'A']
14 ['A']
16 ['A', 'C']
17 ['A', 'C', 'C', 'A']
18 ['A', 'A', 'A', 'C']
19 ['C', 'B', 'B', 'A']
20 ['C']
21 ['B', 'C']
22 ['B', 'A', 'C']
23 ['B', 'C']
24 ['C', 'C', 'C']
25 ['A']
26 ['C', 'A', 'B', 'B']
27 ['B', 'A', 'A']
29 ['A', 'B']
30 ['B']
31 ['A', 'C', 'A']
32 ['C', 'C']
33 ['C', 'C', 'C', 'B']
34 ['B']
35 ['C', 'C', 'C', 'A']
36 ['A']
37 ['A', 'C', 'C']
38 ['B', 'B']
39 ['B', 'C']
40 ['C']
42 ['C', 'A']
43 ['C']
44 ['C', 'B']
45 ['C']
46 ['C', 'C']
47 ['B', 'C']
```

Selecting criterion was not developed because it is too broad for a same question. However, lists with only one element have ids for required  sampling point.

Answer (score 2):

Use PyQGIS, I hope this will help a lot:

1. Iterate over the polygon layer (feature1)
2. Iterate over the points (nested loop) (feature2)
3. Use the following command for check: *feature1.geometry().contains(feature2.geometry())*
4. If pass: Incerement variable, or store result to an attribute field, or cumulate ID's to a list for selection

You can try or modify this code:

```
path = "d:/"
filename1 = "layer1" // grid layer
layer1 = QgsVectorLayer(path + filename1 + ".shp", filename1, "ogr")
idx = layer.fields().lookupField('status')

filename2 = "layer2" // point layer
layer2 = QgsVectorLayer(path + filename2 + ".shp", filename1, "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer2)

polygons = [feature for feature in layer1.getFeatures()]
points = [feature for feature in layer2.getFeatures()] 

for feature1 in polygons:
    for feature2 in points:
        i = 0
        ids = []
        if feature1.geometry().contains(feature2.geometry()):
            i += 1
            ids.append(feature2.id())
            last_id = feature2.id()
    # store the result to grid, if you want
    attrs = { idx :  i}
    layer1.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({feature1.id(): attrs})
    # or select points
    layer2.setSelectedFeatures(last_id)
    #layer2.setSelectedFeatures(ids)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer1)
```

Comment: Could you do this task via Processing Modeler?

Comment: I am not sure about that, it seems too complex for that.
Just use Python Console in QGIS.

Comment: @pnz Did you try this code out? I tested it and it doesn't work. There are several issues (by the way, comments in python are placed with # character; not with C/C++ notation). I solved it by determining a list of lists (matrix) with ids of points within each 25x25 squares. At this point, it is relatively easy to select sampling points based in criteria above exposed.

Comment: I tried to run several times too, but got error result

Comment: I just wrote it in Notepad++, haven't tested it. @xunilk I'll edit the comments, thanks :). And I edited the addMapLayer function. The others should be good.